# Access other user's folder via FTP

Tags: linux, ftp, filezilla

Before buying NAS, I try to use FTP to transfer data from the office to my home.

The computer at home has two user; the first one is called `user` and the other one is called `admin`.

The FTP server is running in `user`, but my data is located in the folder that only `admin` can access.

Is it able to access `admin`'s folder via FTP (using FileZilla) if I already have `admin`'s password?

Most important of all, remote desktop might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`my data is located in the folder that only admin can access.` Based on this information, the answer would be no, You can't access this folder through FTP, let alone FileZilla. That said, you will be able see the folder name through FTP if it a sub-directory for the Root Directory of the FTP.
 
 Remote Desktop is good as long as the session remains **Encrypted** and the Server is protected by a **Strong Password**. However, I personally use **X11VNC** over Remote Desktop because of its flexibility for different clients.